# awkの出力が思うようにいかない

Tags: awk

下のコードを実際に動した時に

```
203100B
203101K
.
.
.
```

となって欲しいのですが全部最後に付く文字が `A` になってしまいます。
どこがおかしいのか教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{

    for(i = 0;i <= 40; i++){
        zyu[i]=int(i/10)
            iti[i]=i%10
            check[i]=((33+zyu[i]*3+iti[i]*2)%11)%10

            if (check[i]=0) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"B")
            else if (check[i]=1) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"A")
            else if (check[i]=2) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"K")
            else if (check[i]=3) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"J")
            else if (check[i]=4) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"H")
            else if (check[i]=5) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"G")
            else if (check[i]=6) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"F")
            else if (check[i]=7) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"E")
            else if (check[i]=8) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"D")
            else if (check[i]=9) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"C")
    }
}
```

Comment: [Teratail:awkの出力がうまくいきません](https://teratail.com/questions/bhoi4sm0xpqpak)

Answer (score 0):

`if` 文 (および `else`) で `=` が一つのため、比較ではなく **代入になっているのが原因** だと思います。

値の比較を行うには `==` を使用してください。

**修正例 (抜粋):**

```
            if (check[i]==0) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"B")
            else if (check[i]==1) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"A")
            else if (check[i]==2) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"K")
            else if (check[i]==3) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"J")
            else if (check[i]==4) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"H")
            else if (check[i]==5) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"G")
            else if (check[i]==6) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"F")
            else if (check[i]==7) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"E")
            else if (check[i]==8) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"D")
            else if (check[i]==9) printf("2031%02d%1s\n",i,"C")
```